# How can I dynamically filter an Angular observable for different views?

Tags: angular, filter, observable

I have a message service that returns messages of various types, including some that are marked for display on page load. The messages are set up as an observable in my service:

```
this.http.get(this.messagesUrl, { withCredentials: true })
    .map(response => response.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
        this.messageStore.messages = data;
        this._messages.next(Object.assign({}, this.messageStore).messages);
    }, error => {
        console.log('Could not retrieve messages.');
    });
```

Say I want to grab just the mesages with the `onload` property for display, and then later I want to show just messages of a certain type (maintenance, marketing, etc.). How can I filter the observable further on demand, either in the component or via service methods?

It's maybe worth mentioning that I inject the service at the app level because my views are in a child component dialog.

---

Update: I'm looking at passing in a filters object on the service call:

```
.map(data => data.filter(msg => {
    // 'filters' is an object passed in from the component
    msg.show_on_page_load === filters.show_on_page_load
}))
```

Comment: In your main filter method, keep some $scope booleans and then in your filter method filter based upon those variables. Bind those variables to inputs. Am I on the right track?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/btroncone/d6cf141d6f2c00dc6b35#filter maybe?

Comment: @JGFMK, I'm using filters (not shown), but I'm not sure how I'd update them dynamically for different presentations.

Comment: Well here are my favorite bookmarks for this stuff: 1) https://gist.github.com/btroncone/d6cf141d6f2c00dc6b35  2) http://rxmarbles.com/  3)  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ei7FsoXKPl0 
 4) http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html

Comment: I've just been watching a video on Youtube and thought it might be of interest to your scenario too. (ngRX)  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cyaAhXHhxgk and here's the example https://github.com/ngrx/example-app